# I am suffering from a headache

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countability

**1. I am suffering from a headache.**

**2. I am suffering from toothache.**

**3. I am suffering from backache.**

According to Raymond Murphy *headache* is countable because it is common,  while *toothache*, *backache* and *stomach ache*   are  uncountable because they  are  not common.

In India it is  common to omit the article  *a* with all kinds of ache.

Do native speakers follow the rule in their speech and writing?

Is the omission of the article before *headache* considered wrong?

Comment: My grandfather would have said "I have the toothache".

Comment: In the works of Jane Austin, and other novelists of that period, "I have (or he has) the headache" was the usual form. I still see it in British works from the early 20th, say 1900-1915, including the works of Saki. It is certainly not usual today. This usage has changed over time, and may change again. I may try to tun this into an answer, but it is not full enough as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker of U.S. English, I would include an article in all three sentences:

> 1. I am suffering from a headache.
> 2. I am suffering from a toothache.
> 3. I am suffering from a backache.

However, I would omit the article in #3 if we changed *backache* to *back pain*:

> I am suffering from back pain.

We don't usually say *head pain* or *tooth pain*, but, I suppose we might say something like this:

> The doctor asked, "Do you have any head pain?"

I am having a hard time contriving a scenario where *a head pain* would sound idiomatic.

Comment: Not my downvote, but suffering any of those sounds really stilted.

Comment: Your #3 looks decidedly "odd" to me. I did [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suffering+from+a+backache%2Csuffering+from+backache&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuffering%20from%20a%20backache%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csuffering%20from%20backache%3B%2Cc0) to see if it was a US/UK usage split. As you can see, the "combined" chart shows at least *some* instances with the article, but when I switch to ***either*** BrE or AmE corpus, in both cases there aren't enough instances of ***a backache*** to chart. So I'm none the wiser.

Comment: @Lambie - I was only quoting the OP's original sentences. But I agree with you; in conversation or correspondence, I'd be much more likely to say, _I have a headache_ or _I have a toothache_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suffering+from+a+backache%2Csuffering+from+backache%2Csuffering+from+back+pain&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows _back pain_ might be the most common of them all.

Comment: I just cancelled my downvote, after using [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+a+backache%2Cgot+backache&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgot%20a%20backache%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20backache%3B%2Cc0) to find that ***got a backache*** is in fact more common that ***got backache*** in AmE (again, the version ***with*** the article is too rare to chart in the BrE corpus). It sounds terribly "dated" to me, but obviously not to many Americans.

Comment: As another AmE speaker, I also would use an article for all three, and would think someone had made a mistake if they left it out, except perhaps in a case where someone is listing symptoms or side effects.

Comment: The use of the article is more common in US English; the lack of the article is more common in UK English.

Comment: @JasonBassford That depends. Even the Brits would be loathe to say; I have + backache or earache etc. Though they might say: She has toothache every week, instead of a toothache. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Example of usage:

She has **a headache** now. She often gets **headaches** after company meetings.

**Generally speaking**, the most common way to say this in standard English (AmE,BrE, AUS, NZ, SA, etc.) is to say have a [headache, backache, earache].

**There are tons of regional variations**. But this (example above) is what one would find in any regular English course.

- Did you get frequent headaches while you were in the desert?

However, **these conditions can also be considered as uncountable nouns as in**:

- Toothache is hard to deal with.
- Headache is common in nightclub waiters exposed to many hours of strobe lights.
- Backache can be treated in many different ways.

In the examples above, the plural of the noun can also be used. Generally, we don't use suffer except in a quasi-medical or medical context or an analysis of a person's condition: She suffers from frequent headaches.